# Prime Numbers and Divisibility Algebraic Structures

Tags: number-theory

I have a question in my textbook that I am not sure is valid. It states that if a number $p \ge 2$ has the following property that if $m$ and $n$ are integers and $p \mid mn$ either $p \mid m$ or $p \mid n$. Show that $p$ must be prime.

Is this not a wrong question if $m=3$ and $n=8$ and $p=4$? I am confused..

Comment: The second statement is very unclear IMO. Please list the properties of $p$ in separate bullets.

Comment: $p = 4$ does not satisfy the property, as you can see from $m = n = 2$.

Comment: The result says that if the condition holds for **all** integers $m$ and $n$, then $p$ is prime.

Comment: Thank you I understand it better now I was missing the "all" part clearly.

Comment: Use `\ge` to get "$\ge$" and `\mid` to get a nice divides-symbol. You can also Right-click > Show math as > TeX commands to see what is the LaTeX code for any formula.

Answer (score 1):

You're misinterpreting the question. English phrasing can be ambiguous, but often "if" is used when "for any" is intended. The question should read:

> Take any integer $p \ge 2$ such that, for any integers $m,n$, if $p \mid mn$ then $p \mid m$ or $p \mid n$. Show that $p$ is prime.